# If conditional not working with `enqueue_scripts`

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to enqueue a script if the page template is the archive of post-type `post`.

I've tried using the HTML source inspector `CTRL+U` to see if the script loads. 
I've used both `if ( is_archive() ) {...}` and `if ( is_post_type_archive() ) {...}` to test if the script loads. 
I've wrapped all the code inside the desired JS sheet with `jQuery(function ($) {...})`
It only works if I remove the conditional lines of code.

```
if ( is_post_type_archive() ) {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'infiniteScroll', get_template_directory_uri() . '/javascript/infiniteScroll.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', true );
} else {}
```

Comment: Are you using custom post type?

Comment: No, `post-type` is `post`